# реализация Parse String

Tags: java, android

Например есть такая строка `{"server_response":[{"code":"reg_false","message":"User Already Exist"}]}`
Подскажите плз как задать ей надлежащй вид и оставить только читабельное User Already Exist.

Comment: Учитывая что эта строка очень смахивает на JSON, то стоит распарсить её как JSON и взять, условно говоря, `jsonObject.server_response[0].message`.

Comment: если это действительно json - гугли в сторону jackson (https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String sJsonStr="{\"server_response\":[{\"code\":\"reg_false\",\"message\":\"User Already Exist\"}]}";
        String sCode="";
        String sMessage="";
        JSONObject dataJsonObj = null;  
        try {
          dataJsonObj = new JSONObject(sJsonStr);
          JSONArray server_response = dataJsonObj.getJSONArray("server_response");
          sCode =server_response.getJSONObject(0).getString("code");
          sMessage =server_response.getJSONObject(0).getString("message");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
        }//catch (JSONException e)
```

Но народ правильно говорит, в гугле все есть, учитесь пользоваться поиском.